# C# Download and View pdf file

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf

I want to download and view pdf file in browser with single click .. 
both download and view code is working on separate pages 
but it doesnt work simultaneously on button click cause of HttpContext.Current.Response 
any suggestion how can I handle it

below is code

```
public static void DownloadFile(string filePath)
{
    try {
        HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
        HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + System.IO.Path.GetFileName(filePath) + "\"");
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();
        HttpContext.Current.Response.WriteFile(filePath);
        HttpContext.Current.Response.End();

    } catch (Exception ex) {
    }

}


public static void ViewFile(string filePath)
{
    WebClient User = new WebClient();
    Byte[] FileBuffer = User.DownloadData(filePath);

    if (FileBuffer != null) {
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();
        HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
        HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("content-length", FileBuffer.Length.ToString());
        HttpContext.Current.Response.BinaryWrite(FileBuffer);
        HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
    }
    DownloadFile(filePath);
}
```

Comment: One solution is not to have two pages. Stream download and write to current page buffer output. Second is , write file temporaily on server and then open it in second page.

Comment: @Amit HOw to do it ?

Comment: First tell , File you are downloading is on your local machine or remote machine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this -

If you want to download and open server file call `SendFiletoBrowser`. If you want remote file to be downloaded and displayed in browser then call `OpenRemoteFileInBrowser` method.

```
public void SendFiletoBrowser(string path,string fileName)
    {
        try
        {
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
            using (FileStream fs = File.OpenRead(Server.MapPath(path)))
            {
                fs.CopyTo(ms);
            }
            ms.Position = 0;
            OpenInBrowser(ms, fileName);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

            throw;
        }


    }

    public void OpenRemoteFileInBrowser(Uri destinationUrl, string fileName)
    {
        try
        {
            WebClient wc = new WebClient();
            using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(wc.DownloadData(destinationUrl.ToString())))
            {
                OpenInBrowser(stream, fileName);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

            throw;
        }

    }

    private void OpenInBrowser(MemoryStream stream, string fileName)
    {

        byte[] buffer = new byte[4 * 1024];
        int bytesRead;
        bytesRead = stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

        Response.Buffer = false;
        Response.BufferOutput = false;
        Response.Clear();
        Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
        Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=" + fileName);
        if (stream.Length != -1)
            Response.AppendHeader("Content-Length", stream.Length.ToString());

        while (bytesRead > 0 && Response.IsClientConnected)
        {
            Response.OutputStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
            bytesRead = stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        }

    }
```